# UDP over NAT (via Internet)

Tags: c#, udp, nat

I'm coding a system with server (behind NAT with UDP port forwarding, static white IP) and client (behind NAT without any custom settings).

The task is sending datas from server to client via Internet .
In order to Server knows client's endpoint (and client's router keeps translation table), Client sends every 5 second easy UDP request to Server like "Hello!".
Server code:

```
    private void SendData(ref string destination, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        UdpClient senderClient = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
                    continue;
                byte[] testMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AnyDatas");

                string ip = destination.Split(':')[0];
                string p = destination.Split(':')[1];
                IPEndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), int.Parse(p));
                senderClient.Send(testMessage, testMessage.Length, clientEP);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        { }
        finally
        {
            if (senderClient != null)
                senderClient.Close();
        }
    }

    private void ListenConnectionSupport(ref string stClientEP, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        IPEndPoint IpEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 13001);
        UdpClient listenClient = new UdpClient(IpEp);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                IPEndPoint cIpEp=null;
                byte[] messageBytes = listenClient.Receive(ref cIpEp);
                if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes) == "UDP-support")
                {
                    stClientEP = String.Format("{0}:{1}",cIpEp.Address,cIpEp.Port);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        { }
        finally
        {
            if (listenClient != null)
                listenClient.Close();
        }

    }
```

And that works even!
But only if client under the same router, despite on sending client->server request to external server IP.

I use my smartphone like client's router and try again (client is another PC). But although server gets Hello-request and sends answer, however client gets nothing.

UPDATE-----------------

I need to develop system for scheme:
Server (192.168.0.3)-routerA (static public IP, has port forwarding for server)- INTERNET- routerB(any regular hotspot or router) - Client

Algorithm:

1. Client sends to routerA (in this context routerA=Server) "Hello, give me your data." For router table client sends this continusly.
2. Server from previous message (like STUN server) can note Client EP.
3. Server in WHILE(true) cycle sends datas to Client.

The error is "Client doesnt get data from server".

If that is matters

- server listen 13001 port, Client knows this port number
- In "one router case" case server see client's endpoint like "192.168.0.5" (his local IP) and in "two routers" case, client's endpoint looks like unknown IP (I dont know what is that, his ipconfig shows another).

Please, show me proper direction!

Comment: I am not sure you understand NAT (or likely, PAT). The "unknown IP" would be (one of) the public (Internet) IP addresses the client side router uses to talk to the Internet. A local IP address is not routable via the Internet and no traffic can flow to/from such an address. Is your client sending from port 13001 ?

Comment: Yes, of course I understand that. I wrote about IPs because this looks questionably. Why in first case `listenClient.Receive(ref cIpEp);` gets local  IP, and in second one external.

Comment: What server IP are you sending to under the "one router" case where both client and server are in the same broadcast domain/subnet/VLAN behind the router?

Comment: About port, I was wrong, Client listen any port, like `IPEndPoint ipep = null;
                    byte[] messageBytes=new byte [700000];
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        messageBytes = udpSupportClient.Receive(ref ipep);
                    });`

Comment: Server always has one IP, this is static IP. Client knows this IP (from Client's settings).

Comment: If server is behind NAT, server has two IPs - public IP from router, private IP from behind router subnet. Which is your one IP client sending to?

Comment: How are you creating `udpSupportClient` so it listens to all ports? I didn't think that was possible?

Comment: Client knows only server router's IP, because server's IP is 192.168.0.3.

Comment: Okay, that is a non-routable private IP. Assuming the client and server are behind the router in the same broadcast domain, on NAT is occurring because traffic never goes to the router. The client sends to the server, the server sends back to the client. You could disconnect the router from the Internet and everything would still work.

Comment: No, no. Client doesnt know 192.168.0.3, it knows only server router address (not local). Server can get requests only because router has port forwarding.

Comment: So why would the router NAT the client's IP address if it is received on an inside port?

Comment: To be honest, "one router case" case was mentioned because in this case system works. I used this until I didnt have another PC. Of course for this case external static IP isn't necessary. Maybe I did not understand the question, could you rephrase it.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with what you are trying to ask? I no longer know...

Comment: I updated the question, hope it will more clear.